# NGINX add_header, adding multiple headers

Tags: nginx

I am trying to send multiple headers

```
add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin http://dev.anuary.com;
add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin https://dev.anuary.com;
```

However, instead NGINX makes them into

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://dev.anuary.com, https://dev.anuary.com
```

What's the solution?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Well, yes, nginx is combining the identically named headers.. but it's doing so in accordance with the HTTP spec.  [See section 4.2](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2616.txt).

The header:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://dev.anuary.com, https://dev.anuary.com
```

Is, according to the HTTP/1.1 spec, functionally equivalent to:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://dev.anuary.com
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://dev.anuary.com
```

If you have a system or application that is capable of reading one format and not the other, then it's the problem.  nginx is doing it right.

---

**EDIT**:

The [Mozilla documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/HTTP_access_control#Access-Control-Allow-Origin) states that there can only be one `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header.

The formatting of it ([see here](http://tools.ietf.org/id/draft-abarth-origin-09.txt)) should be a space-delimited list of origins:

```
add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin "http://dev.anuary.com https://dev.anuary.com";
```

But really, you're [supposed to be](http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/#access-control-allow-origin-response-hea) echoing the `Origin` header supplied by the client instead of generating one out of the blue.  This is probably more appropriate:

```
if ($http_origin ~* "^https?://dev\.anuary\.com$" ) {
    add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin $http_origin;
}
```

Comment: Well, the latter doesn't work in FireFox 9 or any other version. Which an issue.

Comment: @Guy Nor should it.  See edit.

Comment: **NOTE:** If the given solution doesn't work for you, read [this](https://github.com/h5bp/server-configs/issues/85) and [this](https://github.com/h5bp/server-configs/blob/master/nginx/conf/cross-domain-fonts.conf). It's enlightening, and you may find the reason it isn't working.

Comment: Can the value of Access-Control-Allow-Origin be regexp?

Comment: Would you mind extending your example to multiple origins (Eg. `http://example.com` and `http://localhost:3000`)?

Comment: Found it [there](https://gist.github.com/alexjs/4165271): `$http_origin ~* (example\.com$|localhost$)`

Comment: If you use if inside a location block it will break things. https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/depth/ifisevil/

Comment: Here's a better solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29113949/65985

Answer (score -3):

I was facing the same issue as multiple sub domains in my network trying to access resources and `nginx` was not setup properly. Here is how I fixed it.

```
add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin https://*.your-domain-name.com;
```

I hope this helps.